# Extending Builtin Array, super() behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to extend JS's native `Array` such that I have an array that implements a random shuffle, as such:

```
 class RandomArray extends Array {

  // Fisher Yates shuffle. Shuffles from the back. 
  // Performs n = size number of shuffles. 
  shuffle(size) {
    size = size || this.length

    if (size > this.length) {
      throw RangeError("Number of shuffles must be fewer than elements in array")
    }

    let curr = this.length, min = this.length - size
    let rand

    while (curr !== min) {
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * curr)
      curr -= 1
      this._swap(curr, rand)
    }

    return this
  }

  // in-place swapping of two elements in the array
  // at indices x and y respectively
  _swap(x, y) {
    let tmp = this[x]
    this[x] = this[y]
    this[y] = tmp
  }
```

However, if I do this, I'm unable to use the spread operator with a lot of arguments, like so:

```
let integers = Array.from({length: 100000}, (d, i) => i))
let ints = new RandomArray(...integers)      // throws RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So I've decided to try to modify the constructor to take a single list instead of the usual variadic arguments:

```
class RandomArrayIfAtFirstYouDontSucceed extends Array {
  constructor(lst) {
    super()
    for (let item of lst) super.push(item)
  }

  ...
}
```

This seems to work really well, until later, when this happens:

```
let integers = Array.from({length: 100000}, (d, i) => i))
let ints = new RandomArrayIfAtFirstYouDontSucceed(integers)  // no more range error, yay!
ints.length         // prints out 100000, yay!
ints.slice(88)      // but now this throws TypeError: lst[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

I'm thinking that `super()` does something a little weird with the `this`, and that's somehow mucking around with the iterator protocol, but it seems like there's a lot of warnings out there about extending native arrays, some of whihc I don't really understand. Can someone help explain please?

Btw, I'm using Node v10.11.0 and Babel 7.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

> if I do this, I'm unable to use the spread operator with a lot of arguments, like so:
>
> ```
> let integers = Array.from({length: 100000}, (d, i) => i))
> let ints = new RandomArray(...integers)
> ```

Yes, you are never able to use the spread syntax with a lot of arguments - they just don't all fit on the stack. This has nothing to do with your `RandomArray` class.

Instead of modifying the constructor so that it conflicts with the `new Array(length)` signature contract, just use

```
let integers = RandomArray.from({length: 10000}, (_, i) => i);
console.log(integers.length);
console.log(integers.slice(0, 88));
```

Comment: ah. i should have realized that `RandomArray` will also inherit a `from` method from `Array`.